# BeanPropertySqlParameterSource map if not null

Tags: spring, dao, spring-jdbc, mapper

Currently I have my own version of SqlParameterSource, which integrates both BeanPropertySqlParameterSource and MapSqlParameterSource; however, I still want more flexibility with it.

So my question is: Is there a way to map every property of a component if its not null, using some build in functionality of BeanPropertySqlParameterSource, or do I need to write my own parser?